# How to take multiple lines Input in char arrays without overwriting using getline()

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++. I am basically trying to take input from user in multiple lines using getline(). But it is overwriting the input every time. Is there any way to get input in char array and not overwrite the previous line or some way to take input in string array and convert it into char array?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int lines;
    char sentence[1000];
    cout << "Enter Number of lines to write: ";
    cin >> lines;

    for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
        cin.getline(sentence, 1000);
    }

    ofstream infile("myfile.txt");
    infile << sentence;
    infile.close();
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your goal to write the user input to a file, or to store all of it (simultaneously) in `sentence`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Open the destination file before you start asking for user input.
2. In the loop where you ask user input, after every input, dump (append) the buffer content to the destination file.

Something like (pseudocode, not tested)

```
int main() {
  int lines;
  char sentence[1000];
  cout << "Enter Number of lines to write: ";
  cin >> lines;

  // prepare the destination file
  ofstream infile("myfile.txt");

  // now start taking inputs
  for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
      cin.getline(sentence, 1000);
      infile << sentence;          // copy / dump the user input to file
                                   // before you read the next input in same buffer
  }
  
  infile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One of them the previous answer. But after `cin >> lines;` probably `cin.getline(sentence, 1000);` can be skipped once. There are two ways to avoid it:

1. `std::cin.ignore();` after `cin >> lines;`
2. To get any input from user via string then convert to some information like this:

```
std::string s{};
std::getline(std::cin, s);
const auto lines = std::stoul(s);
...
```